# Cleaning up a Choropleth Map

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

Good afternoon Stack!!

Pretty straight forward question here. I built a Choropleth to show the density of the soldiers I have where in my army reserve unit. The problem I have is that the map results come back in pretty much monochrome. its not the green scale I used in fill. Am I dumb and missed something??

For obvious reasons I'm not going to share what the map looks like now so any advice is warmly welcomed.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import json
from folium import plugins


##Create data frame
df = pd.read_csv('soldier data.csv')
numSoldiersSeries = df.groupby('Zip').count()
soldiersByZip = pd.DataFrame()

soldiersByZip['ZCTA5CE10'] = [str(i) for i in numSoldiersSeries.index]
soldiersByZip['numSoldiers'] = numSoldiersSeries.values


#Create Zipcode Overlay
with open('pa.geojson', 'r') as f:
    pa = json.load(f)

##Create starting map
neMap = folium.Map(location=[40.767937,-73.982155], zoom_start=7)


##Create color overlay
folium.Choropleth(geo_data = pa, data=soldiersByZip, 
                  columns=['ZCTA5CE10', 'numSoldiers'],
                  key_on='feature.properties.ZCTA5CE10',
                  fill_color='YlGn', 
                  fill_opacity=.2,
                  line_opacity=1).add_to(neMap)


neMap.save('nemap.html')
```

Comment: Could you please explain what did you mean by saying output was monochrome

Comment: HI!! thanks for writing back. instead of shading, some quadrants and black and others are white. There is no shading at all. Binary is actually the word I should have used.